# How can pass aResources String to <System.String>

Tags: xaml

My goal is binding the string that comes from Resources.resx file to 
Xaml tag `<System:String></System.String>`

Like this

```
<System:String>"{x:Static properties:Resources.Stringxx}" </System:String>
```

any idea?

Comment: You can do it directly like `{Binding StaticResource Name}`. Whats the problem here?

Comment: Any thing I insert into <System.String> was insert into Button Content.
so like you suggest i write this.

<ScreenFrame:ButtonPanel.ButtonContents>
                <System:String >"{Binding StaticResources properties:Resources.String13}"</System:String>
            </ScreenFrame:ButtonPanel.ButtonContents>

and the output taht I see a video inside the button is "{Binding StaticResources properties:Resources.String13}"

Sorry but your suggestion doesn't works.

Comment: Try this `<ScreenFrame:ButtonPanel.ButtonContents> <TextBlock Text= "{Binding StaticResources properties:Resources.String13}" /> </ScreenFrame:ButtonPanel.ButtonContents>`

Comment: Thanks Gopichandar,
But my ButtonPanel.ButtonContents is (List<String>) and not a List<TextBlock>.

Comment: Ok the solution that I found is this:
I changed my property from List<String> to List<ContentControl>
then in my window that use the UserControl i used this xaml code:

`<ScreenFrame:ButtonPanel.ButtonContents>
                <ContentControl Content="{x:Static properties:Resources.String13}"/>
            </ScreenFrame:ButtonPanel.ButtonContents>`

Comment: Or better.
you can use  'ObservableCollection<ContentControl>'
then  you can use this xaml code:

`<ScreenFrame:ButtonPanel.ButtonContents>
                <ContentControl Content="{x:Static properties:Resources.String13}"/>
            </ScreenFrame:ButtonPanel.ButtonContents>`